# Is there a way to debug Julia in VS Code using the remote SSH extension?

Tags: debugging, julia, hpc, vscode-remote-ssh

I am on a Linux cluster and the details of the SSH plugin can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks).

After configuring my launch.json file, and then "Run" -> "Start Debugging", it loads for a bit (looping blue bar), but then stops and nothing happens.

Here is my .json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "address": "hpc.haastech.org",
            "localRoot": "/home/jakewren/conwel/",
            "name": "Attach to Remote",
            "port": 22,
            "remoteRoot": "/home/jakewren/conwel/",
            "request": "attach",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "node"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have no problems running, but debugging is causing trouble.